# How do I make vim highlight math properly in the align environment?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this, I'm new to the site :/ I asked the same question in TeX StackExchange, and I was pointed here.

My issue is this: when editing in vim, my syntax file highlights underscores and carets when found in non-math text, which is fine, except vim doesn't recognize that "align" is a math environment.

A user in TeX StackExchange suggested that I take a look at my `tex.vim` syntax file. I don't have one in `~/.vim`, but I do have one in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/`. There seems to be no real difference in the way `align` and `equation` are treated in the syntax file, yet Vim highlights only `equation` and not `align.` How might I fix this?

[image: how do I fix this??]

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question directly since your vim version is out of date.  Anyway, you may want to try the plugin https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/, this might solve your problem

Comment: related, potential dupe: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15090/nvim-highlighting-underscores-in-latex-even-though-they-only-appear-in-filena

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not apply to you since you're using vim version 7.4, but the following is true for the current vim version (`8.0.1525` as I write this).

Sometime recently, syntax support for LaTeX packages such as `amsmath` was removed from the default syntax files.  As far as I know these syntax files are now only available here http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/; scroll down to "Latex Package Support" (or direct link to [plugin vimball for amsmath](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vbafiles/amsmath.vba.gz)).

Alternatively, you can install a different latex filetype plugin which has support for amsmath syntax, for example [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/).  This plugin does *much* more than just syntax highlighting though.